# Why did the Wayne Enterprises corporate building change so radically?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight, batman-begins

Why did the Wayne Enterprises corporate building change so radically between *Batman Begins* and *The Dark Knight*?  I saw no reference at all to the change in the movies themselves.

[image] [image]

<sub>The Wayne Enterprises corporate building as seen in *Batman Begins*. 

A silver/light gray, 3 tiered structure capped with greenish pyramid.</sub>

[image]

<sub>The Wayne Enterprises corporate building as seen in *The Dark Knight*. 

A black, very box like structure.</sub>

I can think of a few (v. poor) reasons for the color change, but why change even the shape of the building?

Comment: @phantom42 The only answer states *"You also have the whole dark-to-light theme of the series."* Umm..  this was actually **light** to **dark**, so if that is the correct answer for that question, it also raises the question 'why did the look of the buildings go in the *opposite* direction to that?'

Comment: Regardless of answers, both questions are about the evolution of the city designs, and are close enough for dupes, IMO. Why might the Wayne building color evolution go backwards from the rest of the city? One could theorize that while the city generally gains hope through the series, Bruce/Batman loses it.

Comment: @phantom42 If you accept (as explained in the Wiki) that they are not even the same building, then that is definitely not a duplicate. (I.E. the 2nd building is the special projects division, to which the HQ was *moved* after the first film.)

Comment: Donald Trump had a sale?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: “The only answer states "You also have the whole dark-to-light theme of the series." Umm.. this was actually light to dark”. You don’t think all the Bane stuff in *Rises* was a delightful light-hearted romp?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  I don't have any opinion on it, especially since it is a *different question.*

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I think you need to re-watch and take a position on this. You’re really missing out of a lot of great Bane-related chuckles if you don’t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The corporate building does not change, in that the Wayne Tower does not transform into the black box structure office building in your second picture. However, headquarters have moved to the same building where the Special Projects Division is located. See: http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Wayne_Enterprises

Comment: I agree, specially since the events at the end of Batman Begins might have damaged the first building (monorail, water mains) and that building is going to need serious repair and constructions for a long time, so it is wise to move the headquarters to another building of the Wayne corporation.